# Какой это тип данных string[] @string?

Tags: c#

Какой это тип данных - `string[] @string`?

Comment: массив строк!!!

Answer (score 13):

То, что вы написали — объявление переменной или поля с типом «массив строк» (`string[]`) и именем `string`. Поскольку `string` — ключевое слово, для того, чтобы использовать его как имя переменной/поля, нужно использовать `@` перед идентификатором. Отсюда форма `@string`.

---

Форма `@"text"`, всплывшая в комментариях — это уже другая вещь. Это задаёт строку (точнее, строковой литерал), в которой нету интерпретации `\` как специального символа (зато есть специальная интерпретация последовательности `""`). В результате, следующие строки:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe"
```

и

```
@"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
```

в точности совпадают.

Если в вашей строке нету `\`, то `@`-форма и не нужна (хотя и не помешает). Ну или нужна, если ваш текст внутри кавычек генерируется какой-нибудь программой, а не пишется вручную.

Comment: Я бы сказал не "нужно", а "можно". Ведь можно и `_string` написать.

Comment: @andreycha  То есть это верно написано string[] vsSource = new string[1];
          vsSource[0] = 
            @"attribute vec2 coord;
                 void main() {
                 gl_Position = vec4(coord, 0.0, 1.0);
             }";

Comment: @SVD102, оооо :-) похоже вопрос-то о другом совсем :-)

Comment: @SVD102, [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx). И да, это нормальная запись. Хотя конкретно в данном примере нет никакой разницы использовать `@` или нет

Comment: @andreycha: Ну, если по каким-то причинам нужно, чтобы поле называлось именно `string`... Например, convention для рефлексии. Или может это открытое свойство, реализующее интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

C # содержит большое количество зарезервированных слов, которые не должны использоваться в качестве идентификаторов. Тем не менее, можно использовать их. По названию можно утвердить, что идентификатор взят "буквально", т.е. не интерпретируется компилятором. 
String [ ] -> опредиление масива, а @string -> название масива.